# mvvmcross with xamarin.ios

Tags: c#, mvvmcross, xamarin.ios

Has anyone tried using MvvmCross with Xamarin.iOS 2?

Are there any special steps needed to get it to work - especially in VS when targetting iOS apps?

How much of the existing setup instructions are still applicable? Do PCLs work using the existing steps on http://slodge.blogspot.co.uk/2012/12/cross-platform-winrt-monodroid.html?

I ask because I am having trouble compiling parts of mvvmcross.

One problem I've hit is that I seem to have missed some of the setup on this Win8 running under VMWare on my Mac.

Here is one error message I have:

```
System.Windows.dll could not be found

resulting in System.Windows.Interactivty not being available and the following failing to compile

using System.Windows.Interactivity;

namespace Cirrious.MvvmCross.Wpf.Commands
{
    public class MvxEventToCommand : TriggerAction<DependencyObject>
```

TIA,

Andreas

Comment: Andreas. `please be careful to ask Stackoverflow questions as specific technical questions accessible to the whole community.

Comment: Apologies for the inappropriate question. Attempting to compile CrossUI.Touch fails with Metadata file "....\System.Windows.dll" could not be found. My reference to Wpf.Commands above is a typo on my part.

Comment: No need to apologise - just try to follow a format so that it doesn't sounds like you are talking just to me :)

Comment: I've edited the question to show what I mean :)

Comment: For new problems, ask new full questions please - or ask on http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/1549/pcls-and-mvvmcross-in-the-new-tools#latest :)

Answer (score 0):

For discussions on the current status of xam2.0 I would recommend this thread today - http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/1549/pcls-and-mvvmcross-in-the-new-tools#latest

Alternatively ask questions here - but please provide as many technical details as you can about the 'trouble' you encounter.

On the detail I can see, Cirrious.MvvmCross.Wpf.Commands is not part of the iOS framework - so won't effect iOS builds. On this Wpf issue, I'd suggest - https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross/issues/171 which concludes with:

> @hugoterelle commented: Have to install Blend SDK for .NET 4 (BlendWPFSDK_en.msi) and all is running perfect ...